# translate geolocation coordinates

Tags: math, geolocation, logic, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to translate latitude and longitude coordinates into coordinates of my own defined map. For instance:

51.876324 maps to 659.33 in my map
0.943395 maps to 2585.17 in my map  other such examples might be:

51.875737 - 505.77 
0.943564 - 2055.39

51.875883 - 1090.58
0.944658 - 1935.42

My math skills/knowledge is kind of rusted, but should I use substitution to find out what is the factor by which the coordinates can be mapped into mine?

Any hints are appreciated
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite possible to answer this question exactly without knowing details about the map projection algorithm used. While lat and lon are angular coordinates on the earth (almost) ellipsoid the other seem to be map (x,y) coordinates.

If your map covers only a small part of the surface you might approximate this by a simple transformation

```
x = lon * factor_x + offset_x
y = lat * factor_y + offset_y
```

with constants factor_x, factor_y and offset_x and offset_y. From two distinct points on your map you may derive these constants by inversion:

```
factor_x = (x1-x2) / (lon1-lon2) 
offset_x = x1 - lon1 * factor_x
```

and same for y.